# Doing AJAX call within timer and hold value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timer

I'm doing an AJAX call within a timer. The AJAX call gives me certain data which I need to make calculations based on the "new" and "old" data. The problem is that the data is overwritten.

```
    function go_timer() {

    var x_total = $('.old_value').text();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://scrape4me.com/yahoo?url=http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/asml.as/quote%3Fformat%3Dxml%26view%3D%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdetail',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser
    });



    function xmlParser(xml) {

        $('table tr.rows').remove();

        $(xml).find('resource').each(function () {
            $('table').append('<tr class="rows"><td class="movers"></td></tr>');
        });

        //end function
    }


    $('.old_value').text($('table tr td').text());


    setTimeout(go_timer, 5000);
}

go_timer();
```

I would like to do `x_total`(old) + `x_total`(new) and then hold on to the outcome of that number.

Comment: you might wanna fire your ajax from a function so that you can call it from your xmlParser so you won't need a time out and things can happen sequentially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x_total = 0;

function go_timer() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://scrape4me.com/yahoo?url=http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/asml.as/quote%3Fformat%3Dxml%26view%3D%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bdetail',
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: xmlParser
    });



    function xmlParser(xml) {

        $('table tr.rows').remove();

        $(xml).find('resource').each(function () {
            $('table').append('<tr class="rows"><td class="movers"></td></tr>');
        });
        x_total = x_total + parseInt($('table tr td').text());

        //end function
    }


    setTimeout(function(){ go_timer()}, 5000);
    //here you can have add logic
}

go_timer();
```

Comment: Im sorry I don't get it...where do I do x_total(old) + x_total(new)??

Comment: I am not sure, may be this is what you are looking for : if(x_total == ''){
    var x_total = $('.old_value').text();
}
else{
 var x_total = x_total + $('.old_value').text();
}

Comment: x_total is a number like "5". I need to hold that number "5". Now the timer and AJAX go again and the number is "7". So now I need to do 5+7=12. And so on, each time adding the new number. The problem is that "5" gets overwritten by "7" and every new number.

Comment: Are you getting new number in ajax response? Is $('table tr td').text() your updated number from ajax response?

Comment: Yes $('table tr td').text() is the new number